# REST authentication

Tags: php, rest, authentication, xss

With RESTful authentication in a Javascript application, state is kept at the client. 
Requests to the server should be independent from one another and authentication should happen on every request.

This would mean that the password or accesstoken (social media auth) is stored at the client in the form of a cookie. There doesn't seem to be a way around it.
Cookies are still considered "public" in terms of security because a possible XSS attack could give the attacker access to the cookie.
In the database on the other hand, the password / accesstoken should be stored in encrypted form as well.

So I don't understand. It does not make sense to encrypt the password / accesstoken and then store it in a cookie. If the attacker gets his/her hands on the cookie, the user's encrypted credentials are just as unsafe, and can be used to be matched against the encrypted password that is stored in the database.

One way or another; if the cookie gets stolen, then the attacker has just the same access rights as the user. How can I prevent this from happening?

Note that I want to use RESTful authentication where the user authenticates on every request independently.

Comment: If you store a __time limited__ authentication token in the cookie, one that changes with every request, then it doesn't matter as much if the cookie is stolen

Comment: The value of a __time limited__ token is that it will expire within (for example) 5 minutes, so the window of opportunity for joe or jane hacker is very limited

Comment: I would tend to agree, but I don't feel comfortable structural wise. If the attacker has made enough attempts on different users to know where to get the data, private data could be stolen in less than a minute I guess. That's what I would expect at least.

Comment: Well you can always apply other checks, such as including a hash of the browser signature in the token, you're making it difficult to hack access, you'll never make it completely impossible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Honestly, I'm speechless; I don't know how one can promote one's app when not being able to guarantee acceptable security. The CSS attack does not seem too hard to accomplish technical wise; it appears to be a very thin layer of security from that pov.

Comment: Did you expect an absolute guarantee..... there's a whole host of different techniques - places worth looking for best advice/practise include https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/ http://www.phptherightway.com/ https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/